# Horizontal, Vertical and?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If I have a horizontal (x) and a vertical (Y) element (axis, perhaps more in the geometrical sense) what would be a proper name for the other axis (Z)? Is there already something like horizontal, vertical adjectives in English for that third dimension?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Visually, that would be *diagonal*.